# Bootstrap Table is Messing up with background Colour

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to put a simple dark themed bootstrapped table in my website. The background-colour I have set for my entire website is overriding the table (I have attached a screenshot). Does someone know how to fix this?

[image: Image of a supposed to be dark themed table]

```
<table className="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Picture</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Image 1</th>
            <td>Tomatos</td>
            <td>$3.00/100g</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Image 2</th>
            <td>Lettuce</td>
            <td>$10.00/1kg</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Image 3</th>
            <td>Spinach Leaves</td>
            <td>$2.00/100g</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

css:

```
    * {
  background-color: #a4e8b3;
}
```

Comment: Change '*' with 'body'.

Comment: * selector is universal selector, which selects every element in the document.